# Full-calendar start date today

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying really hard to make full-calendar to start from today.

It displays the full week when I do this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // Options
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentDate);
```

where currentDate is today.

Reference (click on calendar tab...): http://flickfootball.in/

Answer (score 5):

FullCalendar depends on *moment.js*, so you can do:

```
var today = moment().day();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  firstDay: today
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code:

```
$('#my-today-button').click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
});
```

For more information, check [this link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Stack Overflow answer:

*[How to show a description of Events in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490108/how-to-show-a-description-of-events-in-fullcalendar/36642650#36642650)*

// I am using moment.js for taking a date as today
- today_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

// In this line I am giving the default date as today.
- defaultDate: today_date,

Comment: Doesn't works.
All this solutions just make today come into view.
It doesn't makes the calendar start from today.

Answer (score 0):

**Set the `defaultDate` like so:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('today')
```

**Example**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listYear'
        },
        defaultDate: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today'),  // THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE LOOKING FOR
        nowIndicator: true,
        navLinks: true, // Click day/week names to navigate to date
        editable: true, // Allows drag/drop
        eventLimit: true, // Allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [] // An array of your events here
});
```

There is more in the documentation for getting the current day [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/today/).

Comment: this would suffice to adjust it : 
 firstDay: today

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: moment(), // Use moment() as the current date
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // Allow the "more" link when there are too many events
    });
});
```

Comment: Please do not only paste code to answer, but put it in some context. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP.

First, you need set the time to use:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus');
    $today = date("Y-m-d"); // Use this format
?>
```

Second, call the variable in fullcalendar:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: <?php echo "'" . $today . "'"; ?>, // yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of **initial date** to today's date with:

```
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
              ...
              ...
              initialDate: new Date()
              ...
              ...
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want it like the following?

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // Allow "more" link when too many events
    });
});
```

```css
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: NO.
That's what i don't want.
It displays the week in which that today's date fall.
I want it to start from today.

Answer (score -1):

I found a hack, though not a proper solution.

Full-calendar allows you to start your calendar with firstDay: ''.

So just find out which day is it today and set that to firstDay.

So calendar starts from that date.

```
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getDay();

firstDay: t,
```

Comment: Give a look at @claudia answer :). You might want to update your answer