# Show event description in FullCalendar(v6)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Currently using full calendar with event sources from google calendar which is working great.  I would like to add the event description either as a tooltip or in the list view beside the event title.  I've got a popup on mouse enter working but can't figure how to include the description.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45588069) question from 2017 suggests something like this:

```
      eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.description = event.description;
      },
```

and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642650/21222085) question suggests this:

```
 events: myevents,
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
                    element.click(function() {
                        bootbox.alert({
                            message: 'Description : '+event.description,
                            title: event.title,
                        });
                    });
                }
```

These ideas might work but I don't know how to integrate them into a solution.

Here is my current script with a popup of itemID just for testing:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,listMonth'
      },
eventMouseEnter: function (event) {
        alert('Event: ' + event.item.id);
},
      
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'A*******************************o',
      eventSources: [
 
        {
          googleCalendarId: 'k**************************o@group.calendar.google.com',
          color: 'rgb(246, 191, 38)',   // an option!
        }
        
      ],
      
      
      initialView: 'listMonth'
    });
    calendar.render();
  });

    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well I've solved it after looking at a few more questions:

I replaced this:

```
eventMouseEnter: function (event) {
  alert('Event: ' + event.item.id);
}
```

with this:

```
eventMouseEnter: function (info) {
  alert('Description: ' + info.event.extendedProps.description);
}
```